# useEffect triggers after second state change Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want this useEffect to take me to another screen if those two values meet the conditions.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(userAdded == true && isOpen== false){
      return navigate("/login");
    }
  },[userAdded, isOpen])`
```

I use setUserAdded if an axios call returns a specific response

```
axios.put("https:xxx", data, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        setContent(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
       if (content.includes("agregado")){
          setUserAdded(true);
        }
        togglePopup(); /*I want the useEffect to take me to /login after I close this*/
        
      })
```

and isOpen is a state I use to control a popup component with togglePopup(). The navigate function works only after I open and close the popup a second time, then it takes me to /login.

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the content of `togglePopup` ?

Comment: const togglePopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from here

```
/** You set the value of `content`*/
setContent(response.data);

// ...

/** You the check the value of content directly after */
if (content.includes("agregado")){
 setUserAdded(true);
}
```

Using the setter function of a state is not synchronous, meaning that `content` will not be already equal to `response.data` when we enter the condition. But when you redo the action of opening and closing the popup, `content` will have the correct value from before, so it will work.

The best workaround is to remove the condition and put it in a use effect

```
useEffect(() => {
if (content?.includes("agregado")){
 setUserAdded(true);
}
}, [content])
```

Comment: That way it took me to /login straight away without opening the popup, so I added "if(content.includes("agregado") && !isOpen)" and it works as expected. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is in your axios then clause.

```
axios.put("https:xxx", data, {
  headers: headers,
})
.then(function (response) {
  setContent(response.data);
  console.log(response.data);
  if (response.data.includes("agregado")){ // <-- here is the correct fix
    setUserAdded(true);
  }
  togglePopup(); /*I want the useEffect to take me to /login after I close this*/
    
})
```

**useEffect**

You have a couple of ways to simulate this scenario. Even without a useEffect.

**since you are using React-Router:**

you could return a navigate component instead of listening to a change.

```
if (userAdded && !isOpen) {
  return <Navigate path="/login" />
}
```

**Toggle**

The problem you see here is that a toggle hook is a quick and dirty way to "toggle" stuff, however, this also means you can only do that and the rise grows to create another approach

When you close your modal, you could use the onClose action to simulate what you want.

```
<Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose{toggle} {...modalContent} />
```

You could update the onClose to simply navigate

```
const closeModal = () => {
  if (userAdded) {
    navigate("/login")
  } else {
    toggleModal()
  }
}

<Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={closeModal} {...modalContent} />
```

Either way, I would drop the useEffect.

Comment: In this case, I´m using a custom popUp, not a modal, but you´re right about the fix on the if clause. Thank you so much!